# DataFrame reshape long to wide

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this dataFrame

```
          1
269    0.00
270  141.28
271    2.25
279    0.00
346    1.00
```

I would like this one to be like the following

```
  269       270     271   279   346
 0.00    141.28    2.25  0.00  1.00
```

I use the function

```
df_reshape = pd.wide_to_long(df)
```

but it does not seem to be this

Comment: you mean transpose? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381639/how-do-i-transpose-dataframe-in-pandas-without-index

Answer (score 0):

You want the *transpose*, `df.T`.

Comment: ha thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use Transpose:

```
df.T
```

```
   269     270   271  279  346
1  0.0  141.28  2.25  0.0  1.0
```