# How to transpose (transform) Pandas DataFrame with 2 columns (values should become new columns)?

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know how to transform the following data frame?

|  | value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | florida | name |
| 2 | parkway | address |
| 3 | Tampa | city |

into this one using Pandas library?

|  | name | address | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | florida | parkway | Tampa |

Just need to ignore indexes. Values from column name should become new columns and the final data frame should contain one row with corresponded values from the original `value` column.

P.S.
I've already seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381639/how-do-i-transpose-dataframe-in-pandas-without-index) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe).
But could not find an answer to my question there.

Comment: A = pd.DataFrame( ), inside of this parenthesis you have to add your data.

To transpose your DataFrame A, you can use numpy and perform: 

A = np.transpose(A)    or A.T

Comment: [Félix del Prado Hurtado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11143153/f%c3%a9lix-del-prado-hurtado) but I don't want to have indexes as column names. The goal is to have values from the original `name` column to be new column names.

Comment: I am not very sure about your concept. also adding some code to the post will help. 
Think about the dataframe as a matrix, where row=index and columns=columns. You can rename these indexes or columns.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(columns="name", values="value", index=None, aggfunc="first").reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @RobRaymond thanks, this code works for me, and do what I need

Comment: @FélixdelPradoHurtado Rob's comment helps to solve the problem.